# How to transform a String to a Long?

Tags: java, sql

I have a TA_PUNCH table as

```
CREATE TABLE TA_PUNCH(
Punch_id bigint not null auto_increment,
Emp_id int references TA_EMP_BADGE.Emp_id,
txn_type int,
Punch_time bigint,
Last_update_time DATETIME,
Last_user varchar(20) references Trace_user.Username,
Primary key(Punch_id));
```

I am storing `punch_time` in long in `yyyymmdd` format. But now user gives a string in `yyyymmdd` format and I have to retrieve records of that user in last 7 days. How can I proceed?

What conversions should be done?

Answer (score 3):

Use Long.valueOf like:

```
Long.valueOf(userProvidedString)
```

Where userProvidedString is a String like "yyyymmdd", e.g.

```
Long.valueOf("20120720")
```

Will return the long 20120720